# How to call the tap on the back-button in the UINavigationBar programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to call the tap on the back-button in the UINavigationBar programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your view controller, simply call:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```